# Can the Viewbox only contain square Grid inside of it?

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, windows-10, uwp-xaml, viewbox

I just want to know whether the Viewbox is only capable of containing the Squre elements like square grid or not? **Can the Viewbox contain rectangle grids?**

**reason of my question:**
I'm trying to place rectangle Grid into Viewbox control but when i do that it leaves extra margin from up and Down side in a viewbox to make the element as squre.

**My Code:**

```
<ListView Grid.Row="9"
                     x:Name="lstView"
                     CanDragItems="True"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Details.data}"
                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource lvTemplate}"
                     Style="{StaticResource HorizontalWrapView}" />

------------------------------------

<DataTemplate x:Key="lvTemplate">
    <Viewbox>
        <Grid Margin="10 0" Height="120" Width="170" Background="Gray">
            <Grid >
                <TextBlock Text="abc"
                           Style="{StaticResource TileOverlay}" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</DataTemplate>

---------------------------------------------------------------

<Style x:Key="HorizontalWrapView"
       TargetType="ListView">
    <Setter Property="Template"
            Value="{StaticResource ListViewNoScroll}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel"
            Value="{StaticResource HorizontalWrapPanel}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode"
            Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="IsItemClickEnabled"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth"
            Value="{StaticResource MaxContentWidth}" />
</Style>

-----------------------------------------------

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ListViewNoScroll">
    <ItemsPresenter />
</ControlTemplate>

------------------------------------------------
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="HorizontalWrapPanel">
    <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"
              Margin="{StaticResource ListMargin}" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

**Output:**

[image]

this dataTemplate is of listview having style of WrapGrid. And each grid is in an individual viewbox.

Comment: I have tested your code, but I could not reproduce your issue.  The viewbox that contain the rectangle grids was not stretched as square in my side. Could you show more detail about your code such as the style of `WrapGrid`.

Comment: I've added all the code snippets related to listview. please check and help me. I want to make the grids rectangle without extra margin from up and down.

Answer (score 0):

You've used a `DataTemplate` that means you're trying to show data using a Items Control (`ListView` or `GridView`). The issue you're facing is not a viewbox issue. It's the `ItemsContainer` issue. The issue here is that the `ItemsContainer` takes in a `DataTemplate` and arranges all it's items from the `ItemSource` and arranges them in the same format (handled by the `ItemsWrapPanel`)

---

### How to solve such an issue?

Well you just provide a `VariableSizedGrid` to your `ItemsControl`. I will be considering `listview`, but `GridView` might provide you with the kind of rendering you might be interested in and just replace `ListView` with `GridView` and you'll be rock solid. Below is the code:

```
 <ListView.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <!-- 
         or you can do this if you want horizontal scrolling
         <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
         -->
         <VariableSizedWrapGrid/>
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemsPanel>
 <ListView.GroupStyle>
     <GroupStyle>
         <GroupStyle.Panel>
             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  <VariableSizedWrapGrid ItemHeight="250" ItemWidth="250" Margin="10"/>
             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </GroupStyle.Panel>
     </GroupStyle>
 </ListView.GroupStyle>
```

### What I've done in the above code?

I've done nothing but provide the `ItemsControl` (`ListView`) to use a `VariableSizedWrapPanel` to be used to host or render your `DataTemplate`. So this ways your data will be rearranged to fit the entire area with the sizes you've provided or which were adaptively achieved.

### Edit - 1

After your code updation in the question, your finalized code with the solution I provided will look like below:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="9" x:Name="lstView" CanDragItems="True" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource lvTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Details.data}" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalWrapView}" >
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VariableSizedWrapGrid/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListView.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid ItemHeight="250" ItemWidth="250" Margin="10"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </GroupStyle.Panel>
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </ListView.GroupStyle>
                </ListView>
```

Please note: I am using Visual Studio 2017 for UWP environment targeting windows minimum version 10240

---

### Edit - 2

I actually just googled the issue and found out that `ListView` doesn't support `VariableSizedWrapPanel`. You need to use a GridView instead. More information about this on [This Thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c4762686-1264-4df3-8edb-aa2df9bca42d/variablesizedwrapgrid-outside-of-gridview?forum=winappswithcsharp) on MSDN.

So you can switch to a `GridView` and your issue would be resolved.

**Please Note: So for the code to work, replace `ListView` with `GridView` and you'll be able to see your desired results.**

Comment: oh man, your solution looks promising.. checking it right away, i'll let you know what i get out of it in some time.. thanks anyway..

Comment: i'm getting an error while using "VariableSizedWrapGrid": **Unspecified error. The Panel you are using for the Control is not allowed as an ItemsPanel for the Control.**

Comment: What ItemsControl are you using?

Comment: please recheck the question. I've added all code related to listview and please help, i want to make the grid rectangle without extra margin from up and down side.

Comment: giving it a try in some moments, but meanwhile can you tell me why is the **GroupStyle** that you're using? and i want a rectangle grid so ItemHeight and ItemWidth equals 250 will make it a squre. isn't it?

Comment: @KevalLangalia I have Updated my answer again. Please do have a look